# SweeAlert fo asp.net core razpr pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2
did somebody use this for Asp.net razor Pages. or sweealert for Razor page how to do it please

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hey salvador castillo,

try this way may be useful for you. [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-sweetalert-library-in-asp-net-mvc-razor/)